# How to name a table column including dot?

Tags: google-bigquery

I noticed that if I rename a column name include `.`, e.g., `device.name`, it would be automatically converted to `device_name` in BigQuery.

```
select Device device.name from mydataset.DeviceTable limit 10
```

Is there anyway I can use dot in column names?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dots are reserved for indicating nesting. You can import nested data via json import (e.g. `{device: {name "foo"}}` ).

Query results get flattened, and so dots in query results will get turned to underscores.