# How to change the field name in big query?

Tags: json, google-bigquery

I have a nested JSON to upload in Big Query.

```
  {
    "status":{
        "sleep":"12333",
        "wake":"3837"
     }
  }
```

After inserting it in Big Query, I am getting the field names as :

```
    status_sleep and status_wake
```

I require the field names to be seperated by delimeters like '.' or any other delimeter

```
    status.sleep and status.wake
```

Please suggest how to add the field deimeter. I checked there is a field delimeter key for uploading the data in csv format.

Comment: Related / duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13829677/how-to-name-a-table-column-including-dot

Comment: Slightly modified the question. Is there any delimeter which i can use instead of '-' ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After you insert data with above schema you have record named `status` with two fields in it `status.sleep` and `status.wake`
When you query as

```
SELECT * FROM yourtable
```

without providing aliases - you will get output named as status_sleep and status_wake because dot notation is reserved for referencing nested data.
But you still can reference your data with dots as in below

```
SELECT status.sleep as sleep, status.wake as wake FROM yourtable
```